# How do I traverse a Tensorflow graph using the C API?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

A small program below creates a simple tf graph.  I need to traverse the graph, printing information about the nodes as I go.

Is it right to assume that every graph has a root (or distinguished node)?  I believe this graph has 3 nodes and I've heard that the edges are tensors.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include"tensorflow/c/c_api.h"

TF_Graph* g;
TF_Status* s;

#define CHECK_OK(x) if(TF_OK != TF_GetCode(s))return printf("%s\n",TF_Message(s)),(void*)0

TF_Tensor* FloatTensor2x2(const float* values) {
  const int64_t dims[2] = {2, 2};
  TF_Tensor* t = TF_AllocateTensor(TF_FLOAT, dims, 2, sizeof(float) * 4);
  memcpy(TF_TensorData(t), values, sizeof(float) * 4);
  return t;
}

TF_Operation* FloatConst2x2(TF_Graph* graph, TF_Status* s, const float* values, const char* name) {
  TF_Tensor* tensor=FloatTensor2x2(values);
  TF_OperationDescription* desc = TF_NewOperation(graph, "Const", name);
  TF_SetAttrTensor(desc, "value", tensor, s);
  if (TF_GetCode(s) != TF_OK) return 0;
  TF_SetAttrType(desc, "dtype", TF_FLOAT);
  TF_Operation* op = TF_FinishOperation(desc, s);
  CHECK_OK(s);
  return op;
}

TF_Operation* MatMul(TF_Graph* graph, TF_Status* s, TF_Operation* l, TF_Operation* r, const char* name,
                     char transpose_a, char transpose_b) {
  TF_OperationDescription* desc = TF_NewOperation(graph, "MatMul", name);
  if (transpose_a) {
    TF_SetAttrBool(desc, "transpose_a", 1);
  }
  if (transpose_b) {
    TF_SetAttrBool(desc, "transpose_b", 1);
  }
  TF_AddInput(desc,(TF_Output){l, 0});
  TF_AddInput(desc,(TF_Output){r, 0});
  TF_Operation* op = TF_FinishOperation(desc, s);
  CHECK_OK(s);
  return op;
}

TF_Graph* BuildSuccessGraph(TF_Output* inputs, TF_Output* outputs) {
  //            |
  //           z|
  //            |
  //          MatMul
  //         /       \
  //        ^         ^
  //        |         |
  //    x Const_0  y Const_1
  //
  float const0_val[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
  float const1_val[] = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
  TF_Operation* const0 = FloatConst2x2(g, s, const0_val, "Const_0");
  TF_Operation* const1 = FloatConst2x2(g, s, const1_val, "Const_1");
  TF_Operation* matmul = MatMul(g, s, const0, const1, "MatMul",0,0);
  inputs[0] = (TF_Output){const0, 0};
  inputs[1] = (TF_Output){const1, 0};
  outputs[0] = (TF_Output){matmul, 0};
  CHECK_OK(s);
  return g;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  g = TF_NewGraph();
  s = TF_NewStatus();

  TF_Output inputs[2],outputs[1];
  BuildSuccessGraph(inputs,outputs);

  /* HERE traverse g -- maybe with {inputs,outputs} -- to print the graph */

  fprintf(stdout, "OK\n");
}
```

If someone could help with what functions to use to get info about the graph, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you have a particular traversal in mind, or is [`TF_GraphNextOperation`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3128b43eb0bf37ac3c49cb22a6e1789d8ea346e8/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L857) enough? You can [fetch the inputs and outputs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3128b43eb0bf37ac3c49cb22a6e1789d8ea346e8/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L584) for each.

Comment: @AllenLavoie +1 - this seems the only way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from c_api.h:

```
// Iterate through the operations of a graph.  To use:
// size_t pos = 0;
// TF_Operation* oper;
// while ((oper = TF_GraphNextOperation(graph, &pos)) != nullptr) {
//   DoSomethingWithOperation(oper);
// }
TF_CAPI_EXPORT extern TF_Operation* TF_GraphNextOperation(TF_Graph* graph,
                                                      size_t* pos);
```

Note this only returns operations and does not define a way to navigate from one node (Operation) to the next - this edge relationship is stored in the nodes themselves (as pointers).

Comment: But the node that defines in tensorflow/core/graph/graph.h is not included with the api c, did you find a solution ? To traverse all the node in the graph.. Thx